# Neyman Allocation Standard Deviation for Proportions

Tags: sampling, stratification

I am currently working towards the Royal Statistical Society's Higher Diploma and have run across a strange result in one of their sample papers that I can't work out - wonder if anyone can help me.

In Q3 of [this paper](http://www.rss.org.uk/Images/PDF/pro-dev/Exam%20past%20papers/2010/rss-higher-cert-module8-2010.pdf) you are asked to work out the optimal (Neyman) allocation for strata sizes in a sample.

According to everything I've seen, the formula is:

$$n_h = n \cdot \frac{ N_h  S_h}{ Σ_i N_i S_i}$$

However, in the [sample solution](http://www.rss.org.uk/Images/PDF/pro-dev/Exam%20past%20papers/2010/rss-higher-cert-module8-solutions-2010.pdf) the standard deviation seems to be calculated as  √(nhph(1 – ph)) - in other words, the nh in the numerator rather than the denominator as is usual in the standard deviation formula for a proportion.

I'm sure I'm being dense and missing something obvious, but I have looked and can't seem to find an answer. Can anyone help me? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominator $D$ isn't being ignored. It is calculated as sum of the numerators. The solution in the document is $n_1 = 363$ and $n_2 = 137$. Here's how to reproduce these numbers.

From the Solutions Document:

> The values of $N_hs_h$ are 8000√(300 × 0.3 × 0.7) = 63498.03 for urban areas and 4000√(150 × 0.6 × 0.4) = 24000.00 for rural areas. "

1. Sum  the two expressions to get the denominator.
   $$
   D = N_1s_1 + N_2s_2 = 63498.03 + 24000 =  87,498.03
   $$
2. Calculate the proportion allocated to the first stratum:
   $$
    \frac{N_1s_1}{D} = \frac{63498.03}{87498.03}=  0.725708
   $$
3. The sample size allocated to the first stratum $n_1 = 0.725708\times 500 = 363$, rounded to the nearest integer. Then  $n_2 = 500-363$.

Comment: Thanks Steve. My confusion though is in calculating sh - for a proportion I generally understood this was √(p)(1-p)/n, but here it seems to be √n(p)(1-p).

Sure I'm missing something obvious, but just can't spot it!

Comment: Sorry, the previous comment omitted some square roots. $s_h =\sqrt{p_h(1−p_h)}$ is the standard deviation of a binomial variable with success probability $p_h$.  The numerator for stratum *h*  in the document is $N_h\sqrt{ p_h(1−p_h}$ and is therefore correct. $N_h$ is the size of the population in stratum *h*. You are misreading the term as $n_h\sqrt{ p_h(1−p_h)}$. $\sqrt{p_h (1-p_h)/n_h}$ is the *standard error* or the estimated $p_h$, not its *standard deviation.*